# How to pass the (is not null) in MY_Model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, my-model-jami

I have integrated the Jamie Rumbelow My Model for doing active record queries with codeigniter from github - https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_id =1 and phone_no is not null;
```

i wanted to use this MySQL query in MyModel and i have tried this.

```
$data['user_details'] = $this->user_details_model->get_many_by(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'phone_no' =>NULL));
```

The above one is working correct but i wanted to do the reverse `is not null`. Kindly help me with that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data['user_details'] = $this->user_details_model->get_many_by(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'phone_no !=' =>NULL));
```

Maybe this also works:

```
$data['user_details'] = $this->user_details_model->get_many_by(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'phone_no IS NOT' =>NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , maybe helpful

```
$data['user_details'] = $this->user_details_model->get_many_by(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'phone_no != ' =>NULL));
```

OR

```
$data['user_details'] = $this->user_details_model->get_many_by(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'phone_no != ' =>""));
```